# listing subdirectories/files in linux using java

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

I was trying to run this code on Linux as a normal user but due to insufficient privileges listfiles() returning null.

```
File parentDirectory = new File("/root");
File[] childFiles = parentDirectory.listFiles();
```

How can I run the above code without running java application in SU mode.

- Can I ask the user to enter root password? So that I can run linux commands instead of java functions.

What all options I have to achieve this in java?

Comment: I assume that you already checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143027/java-execute-linux-commands-that-require-su

Comment: You can let java run a skript from the user with execution rights for you, created by the root admin. - *if that is feasible*

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `/root/` directory world-readable or group-readable. In the latter case, you must also add the user running the program to the appropriate group.

World readable:

```
sudo chmod o+r /root
```

Group readable:

```
sudo chmod g+r /root
```